# How to make a JButton that will create other buttons within a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I am creating a user system to hold multiple details of multiple users. so i would like to create a button that would be able to create another button. when the second button is pressed a form will open for the user to fill. I have already created the form for the user to fill but i cannot manage to make the button to create more buttons to work. I have coded this but it does not show the button on the Jpanel.

I have created the following code:

```
private void mainButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {    
        JButton b=new JButton("Click Here"); 
        b.setBounds(50,100,95,30);  
        jPanel3.add(b); 
        b.setVisible(true); 
}
```

This doesn't seem to create a new button within `jPanel3`. Have I typed up the code incorrectly or is there an alternative correct way of doing this?

I would like 3 buttons in a row and then a new row of buttons.

Comment: 1) *"How to make a JButton that will create other buttons within a JPanel?"* What is the purpose of doing so? It is likely there are other approaches better suited to fulfilling the need you intend to provide the end user. 2) This has nothing to do with the IDE, don't add the tag.

Comment: I agree 110% with @AndrewThompson's comments above. Also please see updates to answer. Since the question is incomplete, I answered it as a "community wiki", but please do improve the question as per his comments and as per information in my community wiki answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your code and question is missing too much information to be answered completely or well. About all I can say is

1. Always call `jPanel3.revalidate()` and `jPanel3.repaint()` on the container after adding or removing components from it as this tells the container's (here jPanel3) layout managers to re-layout all components and then re-draw them.
2. The container's layout manager is key for this to work well -- we have no idea what it is at the moment, and some layout managers will allow you to do this easily (e.g., FlowLayout, GridLayout) while others won't (e.g., GroupLayout).
3. There's no need for `b.setVisible(true);` since your newly created JComponent (JButton here) is already visible by default.
4. You appear to assume that it's using null layouts since you're calling `setBounds(...)`, and this is a **Bad Idea™**. While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.
5. When asking such questions, try to create and post with the question a small but complete program that we can test and run, and that illustrates your problem, a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (please click on the link).

For example, **my** MCVE that shows how your code can work:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class AddButton extends JPanel {
    private JPanel jPanel3 = new JPanel(); // panel to hold buttons

    public AddButton() {
        // create JButton that will add new buttons to jPanel3
        JButton addMoreButtonsBtn = new JButton("Add More Buttons");
        // give it an ActionListener
        addMoreButtonsBtn.addActionListener(e -> {
            final JButton newButton = new JButton("Click Here");
            // when you click it, it removes itself (just for grins)
            newButton.addActionListener(e2 -> {
                jPanel3.remove(newButton);
                // again revalidate and repaint
                jPanel3.revalidate();
                jPanel3.repaint();            
            });
            // add to jPanel3, the "container"
            jPanel3.add(newButton);
            // revalidate and repaint the container
            jPanel3.revalidate();
            jPanel3.repaint();            
        });

        // create a JPanel and put the add more buttons button to it
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.add(addMoreButtonsBtn);

        // give jPanel3 a layout that can handle new buttons
        // a gridlayout with 1 column and any number of rows
        jPanel3.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));

        // add it to the top of another JPanel that uses BorderLayout
        JPanel borderLayoutPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        borderLayoutPanel.add(jPanel3, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        // and add that to a JScrollPane, so we can add many buttons and scroll
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(borderLayoutPanel);
        // make the vert scrollbar always visible
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        // force GUI to be larger
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
        // give the main JPanel a BorderLayout
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        // and add scrollpane to center
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        // add bottom panel to the bottom
        add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        AddButton mainPanel = new AddButton();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("AddButton");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks i will alter my question above to make it more clear, sorry i am a amateur to java swing

Comment: @kingo123: you've not appreciably improved your question as there is no [mcve], nor do we know the layout managers used. Please look at the how-to-ask sections of the [help] and please read the Swing tutorials to learn how the library works.